# cakephp AVOIDING repetitive .ctp files

Tags: cakephp, view, helper

Many models in my app are similar, and I've automated the creation of each CTP for the standard CRUD for each.  In other words, the ctp files themselves for each model are identical.  I pass the fields used to create the form as an array to a helper.  I find though I'm just creating the same files over and over in separate view directories.  Is there a way I can refer to say 1 add.ctp for each of the model controllers?    I hope my question is clear enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you replicating controller code? The question is more about coding practices than about replicating views. If your views are all the same, I would probably dare bet your controllers are all the same to. Solve the issue of the controllers, and the views will resolve naturally.

Comment: The models are different

Comment: I'm not sure my response really addresses your insight.  Say a little more... how can I have one controller for different models with different urls?  I never gave this any thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->render('/controller/view');
```

You can render any view from any controller, so if you want to create one "index" view and its generic enough that you are just passing $data in, you could render the same view each time.

You could take it one step further and create that view in your elements folder to completely detach it from your controllers.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/980/render

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/app_controller.php#L389